# Simple Auth with Cognito AWS via Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

I've managed to get Cognito to work on our web React app but now I want to get it working on our Android app. However, it seems that the Auth process works different on Android than via the web-app. Here's the code :

Our React web app code looks like:

```
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    mandatorySignId: true,
    region: config.cognito.REGION,
    userPoolId: config.cognito.USER_POOL_ID,
    userPoolWebClientId: config.cognito.APP_CLIENT_ID
  }
});

const user = await Auth.signIn(username, password);
```

How do I do the same on Android Studio? I've looked at some examples like this

```
        Auth.Builder builder = new Auth.Builder();
        builder.setAppClientId(appClientId)
                .setUserPoolId(userPoolId)
                .setAppCognitoWebDomain("")//What is this???
                .setApplicationContext(this.getContext())
                .setAuthHandler(new callback())
                .setSignInRedirect("")//Why is this here?
                .setSignOutRedirect("");//Why is this here?
        this.auth = builder.build();
```

This Auth builder would open a browser and manage the login there then go back to the app as far as I can see. What if I wanted to use my own UI to get the username and password like in the web-app example?

Does anyone have any sample code on how to do this?

Thanks for the help! It's really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It appears the only hook provided in this CognitoAuth (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoauth:2.16.12@aar) Library is a bundle property, via ***.setCustomTabsExtras(bundle)***, that can be assigned to an app-created Bundle instance and populated with properties that you will find in the Chrome Custom Tabs library, https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client

The CognitoAuth Library's source code shows, in AuthClient.java, that it uses the Chrome Custom Tabs library as part of it's hosted UI, specifically ***CustomTabsIntent*** among other classes, and it will accept a bundle instance containing key/value pairs used by the mobile browser for customization. These customizations are described in Chrome Custom Tabs documentation and source code.

I've been working with it myself and, so far, I haven't been able to get much customization to work, but then again, I may not have landed on the right key/value pairs to put into the bundle. I had to time-box my effort and simply ran out of time but I did get the Toolbar background color to change so there's hope.

Here is what I've used:

```
Bundle customTabs = new Bundle();
customTabs.putInt(CustomTabsIntent.EXTRA_TOOLBAR_COLOR, R.color.white);
```

I had to include the Chrome Custom Tabs library in my app to access the constants used in the Bundle. Note: the toolbar color change is not correct as the Chrome mobile browser appears to be mapping the new color my app provides to it's own values. Not surprised, but I still don't know how to fix it or if I'm just not putting the right value in there.